# JQuery .click() disbable for setTime after click

Tags: jquery

Hi hope I can get some help here.  Relatively new to all this JS and JQuery.

In essence I have a JSQuery `$('#name').click()` event which I want to be fired, then halted until it gets a command to become active again.

I can't seem to get the unbind function to work - although I'm not even sure anymore if this is what i should be using!?!?

```
    $("#services").click (function(){

     *bunch of code to run slideshow* (disable click throughout this period)

    });

(make .click() active again.
```

Pulling hair out.  Probably simple, but fear i may have become snow blind.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: can you show the code you are using to "unbind" the click event pls?

Answer (score 2):

You could also just test for a condition inside your click statement.

```js
var wasPressed = false;

$("#myObj").click(function(){
 if(!wasPressed){
    // Allow click
    wasPressed = true;
 }
});
```

Or you could do it any other way, such as adding/removing a class and using that as an identifier. or as you suggested in the beginning, just removing the event everytime - though that looks like a more expensive option imho.

Comment: +1. This is generally the way to go -- an if statement inside the handler that checks whether the control is enabled or not. Definitely better than unbinding and then rebinding...

Answer (score 0):

Though I really do think that [Shai Mishali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/831824/shai-mishali)'s answer is the way to go, if you absolutely must unbind/rebind this should do the trick:

```
function runSlideShow() {
    $("#services").unbind('click');  //unbind the click event. Avoiding $(this) as other events might possibly call this function
    //bunch of code to run slideshow
    $("#services").click(runSlideShow); //slideshow is not presumably over, so rebind event.
}
$("#services").click(runSlideShow);
```